# Parse multidimensional arrays in GO

Tags: php, arrays, go

I wold like to parse a multidimensional array in GO

The goal is to unserialize a array string a run into a loop to get the values.

In ***PHP***, i use this:

**Code:**

```
<?php
$x='a:2:{i:0;a:6:{s:8:"category";i:0;s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:6:"ruleid";i:0;s:9:"redirtype";i:0;s:8:"protocol";i:0;s:6:"PARSED";a:1:{s:4:"path";s:0:"";}}i:1;a:6:{s:8:"category";i:0;s:3:"url";s:3:"jjj";s:6:"ruleid";i:0;s:9:"redirtype";i:0;s:8:"protocol";i:0;s:6:"PARSED";a:1:{s:4:"path";s:3:"jjj";}}}';
$x = unserialize($x);
//Print Array
print_r($x);
//Parse Array
foreach ($x as $key => $value){
    //commandes
    echo "category is :".$x[$key]["category"]."\n";
    
    echo "path is :".$x[$key]["PARSED"]["path"]."\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category] => 0
            [url] => 
            [ruleid] => 0
            [redirtype] => 0
            [protocol] => 0
            [PARSED] => Array
                (
                    [path] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category] => 0
            [url] => jjj
            [ruleid] => 0
            [redirtype] => 0
            [protocol] => 0
            [PARSED] => Array
                (
                    [path] => jjj
                )

        )

)
category is :0
path is :
category is :0
path is :jjj
```

In ***GO***, i manage to unserialize the string but i don't know how to run the loop like in php

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/techoner/gophp/serialize"
)

func main() {
    var line = []byte(`a:2:{i:0;a:6:{s:8:"category";i:0;s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:6:"ruleid";i:0;s:9:"redirtype";i:0;s:8:"protocol";i:0;s:6:"PARSED";a:1:{s:4:"path";s:0:"";}}i:1;a:6:{s:8:"category";i:0;s:3:"url";s:3:"jjj";s:6:"ruleid";i:0;s:9:"redirtype";i:0;s:8:"protocol";i:0;s:6:"PARSED";a:1:{s:4:"path";s:3:"jjj";}}}`)
    out, _ := serialize.UnMarshal([]byte(line))
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

**Output:**

```
[map[PARSED:map[path:<nil>] category:0 protocol:0 redirtype:0 ruleid:0 url:<nil>] 

map[PARSED:map[path:jjj] category:0 protocol:0 redirtype:0 ruleid:0 url:jjj]]
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you have the option to _not_ use PHP's janky internal serializer and use something more common like JSON? Because PHP's `serialize()` output should pretty much never be used outside of the application that generated it.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. Because i will get the serialized strings from internal configurations files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Golang you haven't any parser for unknown arrays or objects, your unknown data is the interface so first, you should cast the data to an array or object and then loop through it, the below code will do what you want.

```
func main() {
    var line = []byte(`a:2:{i:0;a:6:{s:8:"category";i:0;s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:6:"ruleid";i:0;s:9:"redirtype";i:0;s:8:"protocol";i:0;s:6:"PARSED";a:1:{s:4:"path";s:0:"";}}i:1;a:6:{s:8:"category";i:0;s:3:"url";s:3:"jjj";s:6:"ruleid";i:0;s:9:"redirtype";i:0;s:8:"protocol";i:0;s:6:"PARSED";a:1:{s:4:"path";s:3:"jjj";}}}`)

    out, _ := serialize.UnMarshal(line)
    dataList := out.([]interface{})
    for _, data := range dataList {
        for k, v := range data.(map[string]interface{}) {
            if k == "category" {
                fmt.Printf("category is :%v\n", v)
            } else if k == "PARSED" {
                fmt.Printf("path is :%v\n", v.(map[string]interface{})["path"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
path is :<nil>
category is :0
category is :0
path is :jjj
```

also, this package hasn't any casting method like `json.Unmarshal` so you should do it with your own knowledge of your data.